# Get a count of X in a column that has X and Y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that has values of X and Y. I want to write a formula in excel that can calculate the number of (x)s and (y)s in the column. [image: Screen Shot]

I've tried using the IF() formula but haven't had much sucess.

Comment: Use the COUNTIF() formula. Google will tell you how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula should be something like that for D3 :

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A100, "X")
```

and for E3 :

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A100, "Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `COUNTIF` function:

```
COUNTIF(range, criteria)
```

[you can learn more about it here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

so in your example, you can use it like this:

```
=countif(A:A,"X")
```

to find the number of **X** and

```
=countif(A:A,"Y")
```

to find the number of **Y**.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a variance in the approach, this can be done with an array formula. (Countif is more efficient.)

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A8="X",1,0))
```

In order to let excel know this is an array formula you need to  press ctrl-shift-enter after adding the formula.

Your formula bar should then look like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(B13:B19="X",1,0))}
```

The braces "{" and "}" before and after are added by excel automatically.

Array formula can be used to allow normal Excel formula that work on a cell to be applied to a range of cells.

Some references:

http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/CSE-array-formulas-excel.php

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-build-an-array-formula-in-excel-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"Y")` same again for X